# special character (') in where clause in R

Tags: r, special-characters

I am new to R - having an issue with a special character (') using sqldf package.

```
df <- sqldf("select * FROM data WHERE Account in (‘I can’t validate account') ")
```

I couldn't handle (') in **can't**, can anyone please help?
tried various comnbinations of single, double quotes and \ - nothing works.
thank you for the help.

Comment: Try using two backslashes before the single quote.

Answer (score 1):

In SQLite within single quotes a double single quote will be regarded as a single quote:

```
library(sqldf)

sqldf("select 'I can''t'")
##   'I can''t'
## 1    I can't
```

Here is an example in a `where` clause:

```
DF <- data.frame(x = c("I", "can't"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
sqldf("select * from DF where x = 'can''t'")
##       x
## 1 can't
```

Comment: I have added to the answer an example  of using a single quote in a `where` clause so you can see that it does work. You may be making some unrelated error but we can't tell unless you provide a reproducible example (which every question is supposed to do).